# Magento 2.2.5 log me out from the back-end

Tags: magento2, login

I get logged out when I am trying to work in the back-end, and I do not log from other devices! I tried to look the issue with "inspect" and I found this errors. And right after showing this error, I get logged out.
NB! sometimes, the inspector do not show anything! and I get logged out!
Please, look at the picture

[image]

Comment: Have you increased Admin Session Lifetime in Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Advanced-> Admin -> Security. If not check the session lifetime in your PHP configurations

Comment: This issue, has started lately. When I installed this Magento, I increased Admin session lifetime over 30 min. This issue log me out after 30 sec!

Comment: Try setting the maximum value 86400.Please also check your PHP configuration values